# Cgroup not working in LAMP

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, cgroups

I am running LAMP system on ubuntu 14.04. I have an rss feed using php which runs every 1 hour and MySQL stores data.

The problem is that when my RSS feed works Apache runs at 100% and MySQL runs at 100% so my website can not be used by regular users.

I tried various options like Nice but it did not work.So I tried cgroup which is also not working for me. Here is what I have done so far

1) Installed cgroup:

```
sudo apt-get install cgroup-bin
```

2) reboot

3) Make a cgroup for your user (since apache is running under user www-data as shown in top):

```
sudo cgcreate -a www-data -g cpu:www-data
```

4) Ran the command:

```
echo 300 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/www-data/cpu.shares
```

5) Ran the command:

```
cgexec -g cpu:www-data wget http://www.mywebiste.com/rss.php
```

But my Apache process is still showing 100% when no other process runs and even when some other process like MySQL runs concurrently.

When I run the command

```
root@tb:~$ cgexec -g cpu:www-data wget http://www.mywebiste.com/rss.php 100 &

[1] 3001

root@tb:~$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/www-data/tasks

3001
```

But in top Apache is running under a different PID like 1564 and PID showing in the above commands is different(3001).

I am sure I am making some mistake. What am I doing wrong